# How to block back button feature in IE 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm working on a legacy project where in one page there is some JS code written which forcibly changes the compatibility mode to IE 5 for that page even if I run this in IE 11.

I have written the following code which works for all browser except IE 5.

```
//Mouse Special back buttons trap code start
function PreventBrowserBack(){
    window.location.hash="1";
    window.location.hash="2";   
}

PreventBrowserBack();

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {     
     window.location.hash="1";

});

function ApproveBrowserBack(){
    window.location.hash="1";
    window.location.hash="2";   
}
//Mouse Special back buttons trap code End  
document.onmousedown = function disableclick(event){
if(event.button==2)
 {
   alert("Right Click is not allowed");
   return false;    
 }
};
```

Since when we go to this page the compatibility mode is forcibly set to IE 5 by some JS code this code fails to work.

Please help me out here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe time to update your legacy code? https://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `navigator.userAgent` to get the browser version and for example `if(navigator.userAgent== ...`

```js
document.getElementById("browserVer").innerHTML = navigator.userAgent;
```

```html
<p id="browserVer"> </p>
```

Comment: I am looking forward to blocking/disable the back button when IE runs in IE 5 compatibility mode.